# Rewrite Do-Block to trigger function in PostgreSQL/plpgsql

Tags: postgresql

I created a script to update multiple columns of a table in my database . Originally I run this manually but I'd like to apply some automatization with the help of a `TRIGGER` function. Basically I have an empty table where I `INSERT` values. Based on this `INSERT` i'd like to update the same table afterwards.

Thats my old code:

```
-- Create example table
    CREATE TABLE table1(
                        column1 INTEGER,
                        column2 INTEGER,
                        column3 INTEGER,
                        column4 INTEGER);

-- Insert example values        
    INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3)
    VALUES
        (1,2,3),
        (4,5,6),
        (7,8,9),
        (10,11,12);         

-- Update the table

    DO $$
        DECLARE

            b INTEGER := 5;
            c INTEGER := 11;

        BEGIN

        UPDATE table1
        SET column2 = column1 + b;

        UPDATE table1
        SET column3 = column2 - c;

        UPDATE table1
        SET column4 = column1 + column2 +column3;

    END $$ language plpgsql;
```

I tried to rewrite it in this form:

```
--Create Trigger function
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_trigger() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
    $func$
        DECLARE

            b INTEGER := 5;
            c INTEGER := 11;

        BEGIN

        UPDATE table1
        SET column2 = column1 + b;

        UPDATE table1
        SET column3 = column2 - c;

        UPDATE table1
        SET column4 = column1 + column2 +column3;

    END $func$ language plpgsql;

-- Create Trigger  
    CREATE TRIGGER atest AFTER INSERT ON table1
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE example_trigger();

        -- DELETE FROM table1

    --INSERT values in the hope to trigger "example_trigger"
    INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3)
        VALUES
            (1,2,3),
            (4,5,6),
            (7,8,9),
            (10,11,12);
```

But I get

```
ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function example_trigger()
SQL state: 2F005
```

How is `RETURN` causing problems in my query? Additionally I'd like to know if the `UPDATE` statements in the `DO` Blocks are working row-wise or column wise.

Answer (score 0):

In a PostgreSQL trigger function [you need to use RETURN statement:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value
>   having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.
>
> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger
>   manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e.,
>   subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does
>   not occur for this row). If a nonnull value is returned then the
>   operation proceeds with that row value. Returning a row value
>   different from the original value of NEW alters the row that will be
>   inserted or updated. Thus, if the trigger function wants the
>   triggering action to succeed normally without altering the row value,
>   NEW (or a value equal thereto) has to be returned. To alter the row to
>   be stored, it is possible to replace single values directly in NEW and
>   return the modified NEW, or to build a complete new record/row to
>   return. In the case of a before-trigger on DELETE, the returned value
>   has no direct effect, but it has to be nonnull to allow the trigger
>   action to proceed. Note that NEW is null in DELETE triggers, so
>   returning that is usually not sensible. The usual idiom in DELETE
>   triggers is to return OLD.
>
> INSTEAD OF triggers (which are always row-level triggers, and may only
>   be used on views) can return null to signal that they did not perform
>   any updates, and that the rest of the operation for this row should be
>   skipped (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the row is not
>   counted in the rows-affected status for the surrounding
>   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE). Otherwise a nonnull value should be returned,
>   to signal that the trigger performed the requested operation. For
>   INSERT and UPDATE operations, the return value should be NEW, which
>   the trigger function may modify to support INSERT RETURNING and UPDATE
>   RETURNING (this will also affect the row value passed to any
>   subsequent triggers, or passed to a special EXCLUDED alias reference
>   within an INSERT statement with an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause). For
>   DELETE operations, the return value should be OLD.
>
> The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a
>   statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it
>   might as well be null. However, any of these types of triggers might
>   still abort the entire operation by raising an error.